# Beginner Python Stock Screener

Tags: python, pandas

I try to build a simply stock screener. The screener should download the volume and avg. volume and should give me all stocks with the condition volume > avg. volume.

The Problem is, that something went wrong and i don't know how to fix the code. Its a overall problem in the code and i hope i can get some help. Often i get the message, that the data is empty. But i think there is something wrong with the tables and the conditions...

The first for loop gives me this and this is good, i think there is no mistake in the code

```
Ticker   volume     avg. volume
aapl       31          20
ayx        20          32
nflx       25          28
```

The second for loop is to check my condition ( volume > avg. volume)

but it gives me the following output:

```
   ticker1  ...           Stock
0     NaN  ...         ticker1
1     NaN  ...        Volume_1
2     NaN  ...  Average_Volume

[3 rows x 4 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

normaly only apple fullfills the conditions and it must look like:

```
Stock   volume     avg. volume
aapl       31          20
```

Thats my code:

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_analysts_info, get_stats, get_live_price, get_quote_table
import pandas as pd
import ssl


ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

tickers = ['aapl', 'ayx' , 'nflx']

exportList = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ticker1', 'Volume_1', 'Average_Volume'])

for ticker in tickers:
    df = get_stats(ticker)
    df['ticker'] = ticker
    df = df.pivot(index = 'ticker', columns = 'Attribute', values = 'Value')
    df['Volume_1'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Volume']
    df['Average_Volume'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Avg. Volume']
    df = df[['Volume_1', 'Average_Volume']]
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ('ticker', 'Volume_1', 'Average_Volume')

    rs_df = pd.DataFrame (columns = ['ticker1', 'Volume_1', 'Average_Volume'])

for stock in rs_df:


    Volume_1 = df["Volume_1"]
    Average_Volume = df["Average_Volume"]


    if float(Volume_1) < float(Average_Volume):

        exportList = exportList.append({'Stock': stock, "Volume_1": Volume_1, "Average_Volume": Average_Volume},
                                           ignore_index=True)


print('\n', exportList)
```

Comment: When using pandas, please avoid using loops unless absolutely necessary

Comment: Share sample data, expected output

Comment: I Added expected data in the Main Post

Comment: `df.loc[df['volume'] > df['avg. volume'], :]` should do the job

Comment: Where should i add it? In the if loop? Then i get a other error message :     exportList = exportList.append({'Stock': stock, "Volume_1": Volume_1, 'Average_Volume': Average_Volume},
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax